# Who Created Questionnaire (which User)?

Tags: php, moodle

I am new to moodle ,currently i am working on questionnaire module, in which we create questionnaire for courses(created by teacher , which are viewed by student on course detailed page there they will answer ) . now i want to know which user created that questionnaire (i.e userid ). I have been searching for while but didnt found any answer.

Comment: Could you give us some code or upload it ? Really hard to help you without that ...

Comment: hi hope..its clear now..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the questionnaire table has a createdby field, then you can use that, otherwise, you'll have to do a search through the logs table like this:

```
// You'll need to get the right coursemoduleid first from the course_modules table
$cmid = 27; 
$conditions = array('module' => 'questionnaire',
                    'coursemoduleid' => $cmid,
                    'action' => 'add');
$creationrecord = $DB->get_record('log', $conditions);
$creator = $creationrecord->userid;
```